# React-Native network requests after Google authentication not carrying authentication cookie

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, react-native, google-oauth, google-authentication

I am migrating my iOS app from Cordova to React-Native. I have an App Engine backend and make use of Google auth in the app. With cordova a user would simply log in to their Google account using a webview, this would drop a cookie and they could then access their data as follows:

```
function getSomeResource(callback_method)
{
     $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://myapp.appspot.com' + '/endpoint',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: true,
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function(result) 
        {
            callback_method(result);
        },
    error: function(fail)
      {
         console.log(fail)
      }
    });
}
```

With React-Native, I'm using the https://github.com/apptailor/react-native-google-signin plugin. The auth works as follows:

1. User clicks auth with google link
2. Safari opens up
3. User authenticates
4. Returns to my app

and when the following function is called

```
const user = GoogleSignin.currentUser();
```

A user object is provided.

However, it seems that no auth cookie is stored so subsequent requests to the App Engine backend do not recognise the user as logged in, when using the following RN network request

```
fetch('https://myapp.appspot.com' + '/endpoint', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : 'true'
  }
})
.then((response) => response.text())
.then((responseText) => {
  var responseObject = JSON.parse(responseText);
  console.log(responseObject);
});
```

The question is whether there is any way for me to get a cookie (as we did using Cordova) so that I can use this to authenticate the user against the GAE backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone said in the [Facebook RN group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/react.native.community/permalink/768832576585656/?comment_id=769453916523522&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R%22%7D), you can use the [react-native-cookie](https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-cookies) library to handle this.  However, I really think you should re-think using cookie-based auth, and use token-based auth instead.

Cookie-based authentication is really only suitable for web applications. This is fine with a Cordova app, since the entire app is in a WebView, however, you need to change how you think about your app when using React Native.  You should think of RN apps as effectively native apps, written in JS.

The object that `GoogleSignin.currentUser()` returns contains a `serverAuthCode` param, assuming you configured it correctly ([see the note here](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin#user)). You can use this to get an access-token for the user.  Here is some untested code that does this:

```js
function getTokenForUser(user) {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.set("grant_type", "authorization_code");
  formData.set("client_id", "{clientId}");
  formData.set("client_secret", "{clientSecret}");
  formData.set("redirect_uri","");
  formData.set("code", user.serverAuthCode);

  return fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
  }).then((response) => response.json())
}
```

This will return a promise which resolves with the token object. Example:

```json
{
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "refresh_token": "...",
  "id_token": "...",
  "access_token": "..."
}
```

You can then use this to make the requests you need.